# How to disable multiple commits in git?

Tags: git

So, I've just started using Git, having been a happy (and probably rather superficial) TortoiseHG user, for many a year.

I've got 10-ish commits in a row since the last time a particular thing used to work in the code, and about half of those commits are on my list of suspects for introducing the issue.
The challenge is that the last two commits solved a different issue which prevented my test from working, therefore they have to stay active, otherwise I can't even run the test, and things get complicated.

I would like to "disable" the suspects in my local repo, i.e. update my working directory to the state it would have if those 5 commits had not been made, and run some tests, then individually enable/disable them, to see where things went wrong.

I know I can revert individual commits, but that gets tedious and adds extra changes which then need to be committed/reverted as the search progresses.
There does not seem to be a function that produces a working directory containing the state if with some subset of commits not applied.

But it would seem like there should be a way to create a local branch (which I can delete once done, and never push to the server), which consists only of the commits which I believe to have been safe, to which I could then add the suspicious commits one by one, to see when things break.

Is that correct? And if yes, how would I do this? If not, is there another way?

I'm currently testing various GUI clients for git on Linux -- so bonus points for solutions which can be applied via the GUI of one of these clients and don't require fancy specific commandline parameters.

Comment: Sure, you could make a branch consisting of cherry picks of just the "good" commits, if that would help. But there isn't some magic switch that lets a commit exist yet not exist.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is why developing on branches and merging them into master/another stable branch is a good practice, even if you are the sole dev. You can easily rebase your branch off it's parent if new functionality there is required, much more tedious to "disregard" broken commits since you can't actually do this short of reverting, then later reverting the revert if you want to fix the broken code instead of throw it away. Less tedious gymnastics required to achieve a similar effect are advanced git operations.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest making use of an interactive rebase, which will allow you to reorder and even remove the problematic commits.

Command: `git rebase -i <last known good commit>`
Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Other options could be creating a patch/stash of the last two commits which you need to make the test work, then using git bisect as normal, where instead of directly running the test, you do:

```
git stash pop
run test
git stash
git bisect <test result>
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I presume the "HG" in "TortoiseHG" means Mercurial, and that probably explains the gap in mental model here: unlike in Mercurial, **a commit in git does not represent a change**. Instead, it represents **a snapshot of the entire repository at a particular time**. Rather than constructing states from a series of changes, git constructs changes by comparing states.

Given that, the concept of "disabling a commit" has no meaning in git - there is only one commit which contributes to the working copy, and that's the one you've currently got checked out.

It is very easy to go through the commits *in order* and test them - you can check out any commit by its commit hash, and your working copy will reflect the state that was committed. You can also use [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to perform a binary search through a long list of commits rather than testing each one in order.

If you want to test *combinations of changes*, you will need to create temporary branches with those combinations on, and then throw them away. For instance:

1. Create a temporary branch
2. Use `git reset --hard some_revision_hash` to point it at (and check out) a particular revision
3. Use [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to recreate the changes you made with one or more of the subsequent commits
4. Test
5. Go to step 3 to add more changes, or step 2 to start from a different base point

Comment: As far as I can tell, Mercurial and Git both regard revisions as snapshots of the working directory at a point in time, but store the commits as diffs (because storing a complete copy at each commit would be madness...). With Mercurial, I also don't know a straightforward way to solve this. SVN might have one, but that's a very different story.

Comment: @Zak Fair enough, I got the impression that Mercurial talked about "changesets", which aren't really a thing in git. Either way, the answer stands: there's no such thing as "disabling a commit".